# Where can you get Python 2.6 bindings for Subversion 1.5.6?

Tags: svn, python

I'm stuck at this point with ViewVC

ImportError: No module named svn

I can't find prebuilt Python 2.6 bindings for Subversion, and I can't seem to locate the source for them either!

Answer (score 2):

The bindings ship as part of Subversion -- get the source to subversion and you have them (almost certainly SWIG bindings, but I haven't looked).  I've been using Python 2.6 for a while and although I'm now on Subversion 1.6.x, I would have had 1.5.x installed before.

Finding them is going to be dependent upon the OS, packaging system, etc; none of which are mentioned.

Did you install from source?  Did you install a package?  Does your OS's packaging system split off the interpreted-language bindings from the package itself?  Eg, on FreeBSD you would have a py26-subversion port/package in /usr/ports/devel/py-subversion.  On Debian/Ubuntu, you're looking for the "python-subversion" package.